# How to retrieve the data only if the subscride processing is completed

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I can not find a solution to my problem, I explain, hoping that someone could help me.
I have a requirement to apply a refresh service after every call to the API.

the problem is that I have to wait for the return of the refresh service and make a treatment before returning my data :

```
    this.http.post('/api/ws', json).do(() => {
        this.http.post('/api/refresh', {}).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                RefreshService.data.next(Object.assign({}, data));
            }
        );
    }).subscribe(data => {
        console.log('data from /api/ws', data)
    })
```

I need to retrieve the data only if the subscride processing is completed.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `this.http.post()` only emits a single event, when `(data) => { ... }` is executed, processing **is** completed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I need to wait for refresh service before show console.log

Comment: I see, didn't read the code properly. `flatMap` it is then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `flatmap` and `map` to call the `RefreshService` like below:

```
this.http.post('/api/ws', json).flatMap((response) => {
    return this.http.post('/api/refresh', {}).map(
        (data) => {
            RefreshService.data.next(Object.assign({}, data));
            return response;
        }
    )
}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('data from /api/ws', data)
})
```

Comment: Tanks, it lacks a flatmap return, but at subscribe I retrieve the data from 'api / refresh' is not those from 'api / ws'

Comment: you would have to pass it through the Refresh observable. Edited.